# Advantage of std::wstring over CComBSTR

Tags: com, atl

There are some questions talked about conversion between `std::wstring` and `CComBSTR`, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645068/convert-from-wstring-to-ccombstr), but what' the advantage of each one over the other if both are available in a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

std::wstring has more methods for actual string handling, whereas CComBSTR is meant specifically for holding a BSTR string. BSTRs are used mostly by COM methods and have a different memory layout. Generally you should use std::wstring or CString unless you actually need the memory layout of BSTRs.